# Rails: link_to image tag. how to add class to a tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using link_to img tag like following

```
<%= link_to image_tag("Search.png", :border=>0, :class => 'dock-item'), 
:action => 'search', :controller => 'pages'%><span>Search</span></a>
```

Which results in following html

```
<a href="/pages/search"><img alt="Search" border="0" class="dock-item" 
src="/images/Search.png?1264132800" /></a><span>Search</span></a>
```

I want the class="dock-item" to go to the `<a>` tag instead of the img tag.

How can i change this?

**Update:**

```
<%= link_to image_tag("Search.png", :border=>0), :action => 'search', 
:controller => 'pages', :class => 'dock-item' %>
```

results in

```
<a href="/pages/search?class=dock-item"><img alt="Search" border="0" 
src="/images/Search.png?1264132800" /></a>
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

hi you can try doing this

```
link_to image_tag("Search.png", border: 0), {action: 'search', controller: 'pages'}, {class: 'dock-item'}
```

or even

```
link_to image_tag("Search.png", border: 0), {action: 'search', controller: 'pages'}, class: 'dock-item'
```

note that the position of the curly braces is very important, because if you miss them out, rails will assume they form a single hash parameters (read more about this [here](http://www.softiesonrails.com/posts/2007-8-27-ruby-101-hashes-are-cool.html))

and according to the [api for link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

```
link_to(name, options = {}, html_options = nil)
```

1. the first parameter is the string to be shown (or it can be an image_tag as well)
2. the second is the parameter for the url of the link
3. the last item is the optional parameter for declaring the html tag, e.g. class, onchange, etc.

hope it helps! =)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll accept your answer but let me know if you know how to achieve this with link_to tag as well..
`<a href="/pages/search" class="dock-item"><img alt="Search" border="0" src="/images/Search.png?1264132800" /><span>Search</span></a>` I've added a span tag before closing `<a>` tag

Comment: it's actually the same concept, so you need to find ways to squeeze both the image_tag and the span into parameter "name". you can try this, not the full code but i think you can do it yourself =) =link_to "#{image_tag}<span>Search</span>", ... can you see what i'm trying to do?

Comment: ah got it. yeah I wanted to squeez it in name parameter. but was not aware of #{}. fun times with rails

Comment: This might be helpful to others: If you just want to add an image next to the link's text you just do <%= link_to image_tag('image_path') + "link text", the_path %>

Answer (score 35):

Just adding that you can pass the `link_to` method a block:

```
<%= link_to href: 'http://www.example.com/' do %>
    <%= image_tag 'happyface.png', width: 136, height: 67, alt: 'a face that is unnervingly happy'%>
<% end %>
```

*results in:*

```
<a href="/?href=http%3A%2F%2Fhttp://www.example.com/k%2F">
    <img alt="a face that is unnervingly happy" height="67" src="/assets/happyface.png" width="136">
</a>
```

This has been a life saver when the designer has given me complex links with fancy css3 roll-over effects.

Comment: I didn't need the extra stuff that comes before the link. If you get rid of href you can just be directed to the url.

Comment: @newUserNameHere No worries! :)

Answer (score 18):

Best will be:

```
link_to image_tag("Search.png", :border => 0, :alt => '', :title => ''), pages_search_path, :class => 'dock-item'
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution.

Comment: The best solution, clean and without any unnecessary loop.

Answer (score 11):

this is my solution:

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
   <%= image_tag "image.jpg", class: "some class here" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 7):

Easy:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("Search.png", :border=>0), :action => 'search', :controller => 'pages', :class => 'dock-item' %>
```

The first param of **link_to** is the text/html to link (inside the **a** tag). The next set of parameters is the url properties and the link attributes themselves.

Comment: I had tried that but adding it there makes it a parameter for the string. please see my update

Comment: Yeah, I even wrote that the second param is the url, but then deleted it for no reason :P

Answer (score 3):

I tried this too, and works very well:

```
      <%= link_to home_index_path do %>
      <div class='logo-container'>
        <div class='logo'>
          <%= image_tag('bar.ico') %>
        </div>
        <div class='brand' style='font-size: large;'>
          .BAR
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

To respond to your updated question, according to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html...

Be careful when using the older argument style, as an extra literal hash is needed:

```
  link_to "Articles", { :controller => "articles" }, :id => "news", :class => "article"
  # => <a href="/articles" class="article" id="news">Articles</a>
```

Leaving the hash off gives the wrong link:

```
  link_to "WRONG!", :controller => "articles", :id => "news", :class => "article"
  # => <a href="/articles/index/news?class=article">WRONG!</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole `:action =>, :controller =>` bit that I've seen around a lot didn't work for me.

Spent hours digging and this method definitely worked for me in a loop.

```
<%=link_to( image_tag(participant.user.profile_pic.url(:small)), user_path(participant.user), :class=>"work") %>
```

[Ruby on Rails using link_to with image_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643698/ruby-on-rails-using-link-to-with-image-tag)

Also, I'm using Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys this is a good way of link w/ image and has lot of props in case you want to css attribute for example replace "alt" or "title" etc.....also including a logical restriction (?)

```
<%= link_to image_tag("#{request.ssl? ? @image_domain_secure : @image_domain}/images/linkImage.png", {:alt=>"Alt title", :title=>"Link title"}) , "http://www.site.com"%>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to root_path do %><%= image_tag("Search.png",:alt=>'Vivek',:title=>'Vivek',:class=>'dock-item')%><%= content_tag(:span, "Search").html_safe%><% end %>
```

Comment: Will you please explain some details about our answer ?

Comment: My ans will show output like this:                                                      

<a href="/pages/search"><img alt="Search" border="0" class="dock-item" 
src="/images/Search.png?1264132800" /></a><span>Search</span></a>

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
<li><%= link_to "", application_welcome_path, class: "navbar-brand metas-logo"    %></li>
```

Where "metas-logo" is a css class with a background image