# Ruby on Rails using link_to with image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
<%=link_to( image_tag(participant.user.profile_pic.url(:small)), :class=>"work") %>
```

which outputs the following:

```
<a href="/xxxx/308?class=work"><img alt="xxxx" src="xxxxx"></a>
```

I want the class "work" to be a class for the a href not a query param, so it should look like:

```
<a href="/xxxx/308" class="work">
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Where are you providing the HREF, the path that must be retrieved when someone click's the image? link_to is being kind and assuming it to be the current path. Ideally you would provide, the path as the second option to link_to.

```
<%=link_to( image_tag(participant.user.profile_pic.url(:small)), :class=>"work") %>

<%=link_to( image_tag(participant.user.profile_pic.url(:small)), user_path(participant.user), :class=>"work") %>
```

You should not rely on an empty hash as the second parameter, but explicitly provide the path you want to go to when image is clicked.

Answer (score 6):

The above answer didn't work for me. Maybe a different version of rails?

I'm using Rails 4 and this worked:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag (participant.user.profile_pic.url (:small)), class: 'work'), user %>
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 6:

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  <%= image_tag("A_logo_black.png", alt: 'Logo',class: 'h-16')%>
<% end %>
```

where you have a root path defined in your `routes.rb` file:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'dashboard#index'
end
```