# Could not find a valid mapping for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

So, I'm using carrier wave to allow users to upload profile images. Now ultimately, I'd like the user to be able to click on the image and upload a new one on the fly in the profile.html.haml page.

So, I've tried the below adding a form with a put action to let the user update the image on the fly without having to go to the edit.html.haml page.

However, I'm being hit with this error:

```
Could not find a valid mapping for nil

Extracted source (around line #8):




<%= form_for(@user, :url => registration_path(@user), :html => { :method => :put }, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
<%= link_to (image_tag current_user.profile_image_url(:thumb).to_s), edit_account_path(current_user)%>
<% end %>
```

Where did I go wrong?

Alternatively I've tried this which might be totally off:

```
 <%= link_to (image_tag current_user.profile_image_url(:thumb).to_s), f.file_field :profile_image%>
```

which gave this error:

```
Sites/Friendiose-master/app/views/home/landing_welcome.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting ')'
...l(:thumb).to_s), f.file_field :profile_image);@output_buffer...
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

So firstly, what do you think this error might me. Most common errors ever:

```
Sites/Friendiose-master/app/views/home/landing_welcome.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting ')'
...l(:thumb).to_s), f.file_field :profile_image);@output_buffer...
```

I'm not going to give you full answer but teach you to think how you can debug it.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

That is the documentation for carrierwave. When showing the image it says the following:

```
    <%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <p>
    <label>My Avatar</label>
    <%= image_tag(@user.avatar_url) if @user.avatar? %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

One tip and this is not me being sarcastic but get used to reading alot and googling even more. I haven't used paperclip but I can see the issues from 2 mins googling.

[Ruby on Rails using link_to with image_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643698/ruby-on-rails-using-link-to-with-image-tag)

There is how to create a link with an image.

From that link look at the difference between yours:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag current_user.profile_image_url(:thumb).to_s), edit_account_path(current_user)%>
```

and the correct way:

```
<%=link_to( image_tag(participant.user.profile_pic.url(:small)), user_path(participant.user), :class=>"work") %>
```

What does the error say you are missing?

It is not always great to give people an answer straight away but the keys on how to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, but it's carrier wave not paperclip I should have mentioned that sorry. The issue is with the form not with the image_tag syntax. Do you use team viewer?

Comment: You error is with whatever is on landing_page line 9. Which is the image_tag as it says it in the error below

Comment: @SonnyBlack can you tick the answer if it helped.