# how can I make an image_tag that also allows you to click the image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, haml

how can I display and image and make it linkable?

example:

```
=image_tag 'pdf_doc.png' href: => p.pdf.to_s target: "_blank"
```

Comment: You might wish to begin with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643698/ruby-on-rails-using-link-to-with-image-tag

Answer (score 1):

Just add the "(" to the image tag.

= link_to image_tag ("image.png"), {:action => :p.pdf}

Comment: = link_to image_tag('pdf_doc.png'),(:action => :p.pdf.to_s), (target: "_blank")

Comment: = link_to image_tag('pdf_doc.png'),{:href => p.pdf.to_s, target: "_blank"}

Comment: http://lvh.me:3000/portfolio?href=https%3A%2F%2Fshoosty3b-dev.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fuploads%2Fphoto%2Fpdf%2F15%2F_steves_brochures_Part11.pdf&target=_blank

Comment: it only partially works. I can bring up the image, I can click on it but its is taking me to lvh.me:3000/portfolio?href=https ....  How do I avoide  the first part of the link?