# How to add http link on image tag using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby 2 and rails 4. I want to add http link into image link in rails. How can I create that?

My codes:

```
<% for g in @pictures %>                              
   <%= link_to image_tag g.pic_url, class: "img-responsive img-thumbnail" %> 
<% end %>
```

I want to create something like below using rails.

```
<a href="/assets/image_001.jpg"><img src="/assets/image_001.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
```

Please share with me if any one has any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `link_to` helper can take a block of code, allowing you to do something like the following:

```
<% for g in @pictures %>
  <%= link_to g.pic_url do %>
    <%= image_tag g.pic_url, class: "img-responsive img-thumbnail" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

More info on the [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper can be found by looking through the Rails API documentation.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

my solution:

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
<%= image_tag "image.jpg", class: "some css class here" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)** take first argument as `link's name` and second argument is as `url`. in your code you have not assign url option. Change it as below

Try:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag(g.pic_url, class: "img-responsive img-thumbnail"), g.pic_url) %>
```

**[Ruby on Rails using link_to with image_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643698/ruby-on-rails-using-link-to-with-image-tag)**