# Rails: how do I add a class to this image src code? Putting div tags around it didn't work

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

```
<% if item.image.attached? %>
    <image src="<%=(url_for(item.image), :class => "itemholsIm") %>">
<% end %>
```

How should it be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [link\_to image tag. how to add class to a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115214/link-to-image-tag-how-to-add-class-to-a-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the CSS class out of the <%= %>

Try this :

```
<% if item.image.attached? %>
    <image src="<%=(url_for(item.image)%>" class="itemholsIm">
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use img_tag helper.

```rb
<%= image_tag(item.image, class: "itemholsIm") %>
```

Comment: Don't think it works with Active Storage gem. I'm trying to do this: https://medium.com/@anaharris/how-to-add-image-upload-functionality-to-your-rails-app-9f7fc3f3d042

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the rails img_tag helper is the best solution !